# How to pass spring batch job params while defining composed task SCDF?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to create a composed task with two tasks running in sequence. These two tasks internally execute spring batch jobs and the job uses job parameters for further processing.

While defining the composed task definition how can we pass the spring batch job parameters?

I am using SCDF CLI to create the composed task definition and expect **start_date and end_date to be passed as job params**

```
task create --name server-test-compoesd --definition "server-apn-psp: server --spring.batch.job.names=apnPlacementStatsProcessorJob --start_date=2022-11-20T00:00:00 --end_date=2022-11-22T00:00:00 && server-dbm-psp: server --spring.batch.job.names=dbmPlacementStatsProcessorJob --start_date=2022-11-20T00:00:00 --end_date=2022-11-22T00:00:00"
```

Here I want to use start_date and end_date as a JobParamter but when I try to execute this task it fails due to Null Pointer Exception because of the absence of start_date and end_date as a job parameter.

Composed task graph

[image]

This task runs fine if I manually run the task and give arguments in this way without the **--**
[image]

JobParams accessed in code

```
 public class Test implements Tasklet {
  @Value("#{jobParameters['start_date']}")
  private String startDate;
  @Value("#{jobParameters['end_date']}")
  private String endDate;
```

**Version Information SCDF**

```
Core: 2.4.0.RELEASE (Spring Cloud Data Flow Core)
Dashboard: 2.4.0.RELEASE (Spring Cloud Dataflow UI)
Shell: 2.4.0.RELEASE (Spring Cloud Data Flow Shell)
```

Version Information of spring batch job

```
spring-boot : 2.5.9
batch-core:4.1.1.RELEASE
```

**How can we pass the job params while defining the composed task ?**

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `--` before `start_date` and `end_date`? I think the syntax is the same when running a boot batch app like: `java -jar mybatchapp.jar --spring.batch.job.names=job1 param1=value1 param2=value2` (notice the absence of `--` before parameter names).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Yeaa i did try. The SCDF CLI threw an error logging missing  -char.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is to use the `--arguments` option when launching the application for example: `task launch server-test-compoesd --arguments "app.server-apn-psp.0=start_date=2022-11-20T00:00:00 app.server-apn-psp.1=end_date=2022-11-22T00:00:00 app.server-dbm-psp.0=start_date=2022-11-20T00:00:00 app.server-dbm-psp.1=end_date=2022-11-22T00:00:00"`

You can read more about launching tasks using arguments here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-task-launch

The reason the original scenario did not work for you is that when you set `start_date` and `end_date` in the task definition, these are set as properties.   You can read more about setting properties in a task definition here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_application_properties_2

Comment: Hey @Glen our aim is to schedule this composed task not just launch it once and currently we using SCDF UI to schedule such composed tasks. Cant we pass arguments while defining the composed task something similar to --arguments while launching it?

Comment: This particular feature is not currently supported via the task definition.   Can you open an issue on the Spring Cloud Data Flow that describes this feature.   Thanks.